# Problem with getting the user or session object aflter successfull sigin in to Google in NEXT JS from the server site

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, prisma, next-auth

After successfull signing in to the google account, at this route http://localhost:3000/api/auth/session you will see this kind of object:`{"user{"name":"xxx","email":"xxx.xxx@gmail.com"},"expires":"20xxx`} but only from the browser site.

- I want to receive this object, this {user{...}} from the server site in file route.ts at direction example app/route.ts and send this object via prisma Schema to mongoDB.
- I am asking only how to receive this object (for example: by GET or maybe other methods/options) from the server site in this route file (api/route.ts). I have tried to import it by using {getSession} or {getServerSession} in this route file and receive this object but this methods have failed.

Thanks

I have tried to import it by using {getSession} or {getServerSession} in this route file and receive this object but this methods have failed.